# Call to a member function bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to update some fields of table users, but i get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\Users\fel\VertrigoServ\www\login\thumb.php on line 79

there is any syntax error in the code?

```
 $user=2;
    ($sql = $db -> prepare('UPDATE users SET (profile_photo, update_photo) VALUES (?, ?) where id_user=?'));

    $sql -> bind_param('ssi', $thumbnailPath, $thumbnailPathMin, $user); //line 79

    $sql -> execute();
```

Comment: See the return value for `prepare`: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED

```
($sql = $db -> prepare('UPDATE users SET profile_photo = ?, update_photo=?  where id_user=?'));
```

Comment: This does not provide any useful information; if the question will not be useful to future visitors it should be deleted instead of self-answered.